# R: Collapse duplicated values in a column while keeping the order

Tags: r, dplyr, unique, distinct

I'm sure this is super simple but just can't find the answer. I have a data frame like so

```
    Id  event
1   1   A
2   1   B
3   1   A
4   1   A
5   2   C
6   2   C
7   2   A
```

And I'd like to group by `Id` and collapse the distinct `event` values while keeping the event order like so

```
    Id  event
1   1   A
2   1   B
3   1   A
4   2   C
5   2   A
```

Most of my searches end up with using the `distinct()` or `unique()` functions but that leads losing the `A` event in row 3 for `Id` 1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lead` to compare each row and `filter` those rows that are different than the previous ones. `is.na(lead(Id))` is to also include the last rows.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  filter(!(Id == lead(Id) & event == lead(event)) | is.na(lead(Id)))
dat2
#   Id event
# 1  1     A
# 2  1     B
# 3  1     A
# 4  2     C
# 5  2     A
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "    Id  event
1   1   A
                  2   1   B
                  3   1   A
                  4   1   A
                  5   2   C
                  6   2   C
                  7   2   A",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know the lead() function from dplyr!

Comment: All y'all are heroes!! Thank you so much! This was more complicated than I thought but I'm glad you introduced the `lead` function too, I'm using the `lag` function in some other code too so piping this in makes a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can just compare every row with the one after it.

```
df = read.table(text=" Id  event
1   1   A
2   1   B
3   1   A
4   1   A
5   2   C
6   2   C
7   2   A", 
header=TRUE)

df[rowSums(df[-1,] == head(df, -1)) !=2, ]
  Id event
1  1     A
2  1     B
4  1     A
6  2     C
7  2     A
```

Comment: Wow that's a clever solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
dt <- fread(
" Id  event
   1   A
   1   B
   1   A
   1   A
   2   C
   2   C
   2   A")
unique(dt[, r:=rleidv(event), Id])[, -3]
#    Id event
# 1:  1     A
# 2:  1     B
# 3:  1     A
# 4:  2     C
# 5:  2     A
```

or

```
dt[, .SD[unique(rleidv(event))], by = Id]
```

(thx to @mt1022 for the comment)

Comment: alternatively, `dt[, .SD[!duplicated(rleid(event))], by = Id]`.

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution using `tapply` and `rle`:

```
x <- tapply(dat$event,dat$Id,function(x) rle(x)$values)
do.call(rbind,Map(data.frame,Id=names(x),event=x))
#     Id event
# 1.1  1     A
# 1.2  1     B
# 1.3  1     A
# 2.1  2     C
# 2.2  2     A
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `distinct` function will be able to solve the problem.

`dat %>%
   distinct(Id, event)`